# How to set style property to div using JavaScriptExecutor in selenium using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, selenium

I am trying to set style of a div element using JavascriptExecutor using C#.
below is the code i tried but nothing happens

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;  
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'rmSlide')]"));
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1], arguments[2])", 
element, "style", 
"visibility: visible;
height: 259px; 
width: 339px;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
left: -81px;
top: 24px;
z-index: 2; "
);
```

All I am trying to do is setting the `display: block` from `display: none`

Below is the Html of the element

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the code right, just modified and added mouse hover on the element, below is the code.

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xpathe here"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(element).Build().Perform();  

IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;  
IWebElement element1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'rmSlide')]"));
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'visibility: visible; height: 259px; width: 339px; display: block; overflow: hidden; left: -81px; top: 24px; z - index: 2; ')", element1);
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are trying to change the attribute `display: none;` to `display: block;` you can use the following code block :

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;  
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'rmSlide')]"));
var script = "arguments[0].style.display='block';";
js.ExecuteScript(script, element);
```

Comment: it should be display='block'?, i changed it and tried but no luck, it is not changing the display attribute

Comment: no error it did not change anything, Is it has to be do with the div property?, initially there is no style.  So i am performing click operation on the div and then the style is added after that i am performing this code.

Comment: Can you update the question with the _raw_ and _unedited_ but _formatted_ and _text-based_ _HTML_ ?

Comment: i have updated the question, let me explain what i am trying to do, MouseHover on Quick Links will load the li elements like dropdown.  But the drop down is very quick cannot perform any actions on it. so i am trying to block it with javascript.

Comment: If _drop down is very quick_ still doesn't matters. Include the text-based formatted _HTML_ of the _DropDown_ element and text-based _HTML_ of the `<li>` elements please.